# Why do I get "@angular/material@5.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/cdk@5.2.0"

Tags: angular, npm, yarnpkg

I have an Angular 5 based project (built by yarn v1.2.1), where I both use `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk`. My `package.json` looks something like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/material": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.5",
    ...
```

I have noticed the following warning in the build output (even though the build succeeds):

```
warning "@angular/material@5.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/cdk@5.2.0".
```

Since the version numbers do match **precisely**, I do not understand what the problem is / why do I get this kind of warning.

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: material & cdk version should match precisely... u should update material to 5.2.5 or downgrade cdk to 5.2.0

Comment: So not even patch versions can be different? I was under the impression patch versions should not count here.

Comment: Nope it should be exactly same thats how material needs it

Comment: Indeed, making the patch versions the same solved this issue. Thank you very much @AbineshDevadas! If you add your comments as a answer, I will accept it so that you get the points. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@angular/material & @angular/cdk versions should match exactly same even patch version should be same